# How do I add a dotted line as an option in a select tag?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I want to make a select tag similar to the the time zone selection you have in Twitter Settings. The thing is I don't know how to make the dotted line between american time zones and rest of the world. So my question is how do I do a dotted line as an option(which can't be selected) in a HTML select tag?

The answer should be preferably be in javascript

Comment: Depends on how you add options to the select tag -- Static or programmatic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you inspect their source, you will see they just have a disabled option for that line:

```
<option value="" disabled="disabled">-------------</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "separator" that you can add. The usual solution is to add an `option` with the text `-----------------` and no value.

Add a validation rule which makes sure that a value is selected for the selector.

Comment: *possessive infinitive adjective noun*, a rather peculiar English construct if I am to interpret the comment above mine as one.